# Looping through tkinter buttons not working well

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I'm writing a new code to display sqlite search results on buttons using loop. The code works correctly except for 1 issue. I wrote a function to change the background color and play a sound when hovering over the buttons. The problem is that when I hover over any button of the result, the color changes over the last button only although the sound plays without problem. Here's the part of the code involved:

```
SearchSelection = SearchVar.get()
SearchParameter = txtSearch.get()
conn = sqlite3.connect("EasyClinic.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute ("SELECT * FROM patients WHERE (%s) = (?)" %(SearchSelection), 
(SearchParameter,))
results = cursor.fetchall()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
if len(results) == 0:
    print ("No result found")
else:
    for result in results:
        ResultsButtons = tk.Button(canvasResult, text=result, bg=BackGroundColor, fg=ForeGroundColor, relief='flat', font=MyFont2, width=65, height=2)
        ResultsButtons.pack(pady=5)
        def on_enter_results(result):
            ResultsButtons['background'] = Hover
            winsound.PlaySound ('Hover.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)
        def on_leave_results(result):
            ResultsButtons['background'] = BackGroundColor  
        ResultsButtons.bind("<Enter>", on_enter_results)
        ResultsButtons.bind("<Leave>", on_leave_results)
```

Please for you assistance
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the two functions, `on_enter_results()` and `on_leave_results()` as below:

```py
def on_enter_results(event):
    # event.widget is the widget that triggers this event
    event.widget['background'] = Hover
    winsound.PlaySound ('Hover.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)

def on_leave_results(event):
    event.widget['background'] = BackGroundColor
```

Actually you can move these two functions outside of for loop (i.e. before the for loop).

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved the issue. Regards

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that python always overwrites the ResultsButtons variable with the latest button, and this gives a problem when calling the funciton on_enter_results or on_leave_results, because it uses the overwritten ResultsButtons variable. The solution is to more directly specify the button and pass it to your function with a lambda function. I can't check if this code works because I don't have the full example, but something like this should work:

```
if len(results) == 0:
    print ("No result found")
else:
    def on_enter_results(event_info, resbutton):
        resbutton['background'] = Hover
        winsound.PlaySound ('Hover.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)
    def on_leave_results(event_info, resbutton):
        resbutton['background'] = BackGroundColor  
    for result in results:
        ResultsButton = tk.Button(canvasResult, text=result, bg=BackGroundColor, fg=ForeGroundColor, relief='flat', font=MyFont2, width=65, height=2)
        ResultsButton.pack(pady=5)
        ResultsButton.bind("<Enter>", lambda event_info, btn=ResultsButton: on_enter_results(btn))
        ResultsButton.bind("<Leave>", lambda event_info, btn=ResultsButton: on_leave_results(btn))
```

For a better understanding of what acually is going on: [Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result)

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: I changed my answer and I think now it should work. Note that I renamed some of the variables to make it clear that event_info is a parameter tkinter always passes to a callback for an event. In this case this variable is not used, but should still be accepted by the receiving function.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by acw1668. Thank you all for your support